# Sticky nav sticks to the top too early

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, sticky

I have a sticky navbar in my site (Bootstrap based) and that's the jQuery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var flag = false;

        function stickNav() {
            $(".navbar-default").affix({
                offset: {
                    top: $('.header-img').height()
                }
            });
            $(".navbar-default").css({ "width": $('.container').width(), "z-index": 1000 });
            $(".navbar-wrapper").css("height", $('.navbar-default').height());
            $(".header").css("height", $('.header-img').height());
            flag = true;

        }

        $(".header img").ready(function () {
            if (!flag)
                window.setInterval(stickNav, 10);
        });

        $(window).resize(function () {
            $(window).off('.affix');
            $('.navbar-default').removeData('bs.affix').removeClass('affix affix-top affix-bottom');
            stickNav();
        });
```

and the css:

```
.affix {
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The problem is that the nav is stick to the top too early, here is a live example: http://nave.net23.net/Bootstrap/index.html

My question is how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks fine to me, the nav sticks to the top as soon as you scroll to the point that the nav is touching the top of the browser window.

Comment: That is the way it is currently working, as soon as the header is no longer visible, the nav sticks to the top.

Comment: @APAD1 Thanks, in Firefox it works fine, but in Chrome  it look like this: http://screencast.com/t/Mv8Ex3AHj , why?

Comment: Hmmm that is strange. I am using Chrome 45 and it looks fine and looks identical to how it does in Firefox for me as well. Try clearing your cache, maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: I think you're both right. I saw what @Tal is talking about in Chrome, then I resized, and it seemed to work properly. Something with your resize event, or the stickNav function not calling properly at start - could also pertain to the images not loading for me due to ABP. - In that train of thought, do you have an ad-blocker installed that prevents the images in the header from loading properly?

Comment: Turned off ABP - now I just see your obnoxious pop-up ad. After, the issue still seems prevalent unless you issue the two lines as shown in my answer. Doesn't seem to be ad-block related.

Comment: @mark.hch Sorry about the ad, the hosting company inject them to the page

Comment: Lol, no biggie - sorry for the complaint! Would never prevent me from assisting someone, as I understand the use, I just prefer not to myself, as I'm more of a "Keep the customer happy, and they'll keep coming back." kind of guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I load the page and am having the issue in Chrome (44.0.2403.130 m), I can issue the following two lines into the console, and then scrolling seems to work properly (as seen in Firefox). Perhaps just call these manually in the page load function:

```
$(window).off('.affix');
$('.navbar-default').removeData('bs.affix').removeClass('affix affix-top affix-bottom');
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I can fix it from this point. EDIT: can you pleas remove the GIF example? The website is befor the production and I don't want that random people will see it...

Comment: Chances of someone randomly noticing it, and actually taking the information into any account whatsoever, are very very unlikely, but in any case, I've initiated the process of having it removed. I can keep you posted. In the meantime, thanks much for the upvote/correct answer!